# Avoid self-toggle through event propagation in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, stoppropagation, event-propagation

I have a tooltip directive which should open/close on click and additionally close on arbitrary click. Since `angular-translate` does not allow to alter the content of the element itself I instead append the directive's elements.

The directive looks somewhat like this (please be aware that this is a simplified version):

```
{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    compile: function(element)
    {
        element.after('<div class="toggle"></div>
            <div class="message" ng-show="active"></div>');
    },
    link: function(scope, element)
    {
        angular.element(element.siblings('toggle')).click(function()
        {
            scope.$apply(function()
            {
                scope.active = !scope.active;
            }
        });
        angular.element(document).click(function()
        {
            scope.$apply(function()
            {
                scope.active = false;
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

The problem with that is that the click event on the element is triggered (`scope.active = true`) and then propagated to document whereas it is instantly closed.

If I stop propagation however, it works fine for most cases, the one case it doesn't is when I have multiple instances of the directive on my page and click one after another (the first one opened should close and the other one should open but due to the propagation being stopped the `document.click` event of the other instance doesn't fire.

**Edit:** [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/yd6nt10z/) demonstrates the problem. If you click the green box and click it again it works, if you click the green box and then the background it works, if you click the green box and then the other green box however both are open, although the first one should close.
If you remove the `event.stopPropagation()` on `line 20` the hint doesn't show at all since the click on the box is fired first, the hint is shown but after further event propagation the click on background fires as well and instantly closes it again.

---

*If there is an overall better solution to my problem I'd appreciate that as well*

Comment: Can you give an example jsfiddle with which to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sure, check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the solutions that will help you.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/2p5747yu/3/).

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      var self = this;
    }
  ])
  .directive('hintDirective', ['$compile',
    function($compile) {
      var directiveHint = [];
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude><span ng-click="toggle($event)" class="toggle"></span><div class="message" ng-show="active">Hint Message</div>',
        link: function(scope, element) {
          scope.active = false;
          directiveHint.push(scope);
          var span = element.find('span')[1];
          scope.toggle = function($ev) {
            scope.active = !scope.active;
            closeOther(scope);
            $ev.stopPropagation();
          }

          function closeOther(scope) {
            angular.forEach(directiveHint, function(sc) {
              if (sc != scope) {
                closeActive(sc)
              }
            });
          }

          function closeAll() {
            angular.forEach(directiveHint, function(sc) {
              closeActive(sc)
            });
          }

          function closeActive(sc) {
            if (sc.active)
              sc.active = false;
          }

          function documentClick(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              closeAll();
            });
          }
          var $body = angular.element(document.body);
          if (!$body.hasClass('hint-directive-click')) {
            angular.element(document).bind('click', documentClick);
            $body.addClass('hint-directive-click');
          }

          scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            angular.forEach(directiveHint, function(sc, i) {
              if (sc == scope)
                directiveHint.splice(i);
            });
          })
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.split {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: green;
}
p {
  float: left;
}
.message {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="split">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p hint-directive>
      Text1
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="split">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p hint-directive>
      Text2
    </p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="text3Enable">Enable text3</label>
    <p hint-directive ng-if="text3Enable">
      Text3
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```